Running air handler in fan-only mode
I've been trying to figure out how to run the fan on my air handler without having to also run the heating or cooling. I've found a solution, but I don't understand why the system would be set up as if this is the intended solution. Maybe someone with HVAC experience can explain this to me.
I have a Lenox G40UH-24A-045-01 gas furnace, whose fan is also used for cooling. It has a 21D83M-843 furnace control board attached to it. The control board is connected to the thermostat.
Here's what the control board looks like.

The pins on the bottom with screws connect to the thermostat and are used to send 24V AC signals to turn on either heat, cooling, or the fan.
Y – cooling
W – heating
G – fan
R – 24V AC
C – common
The spade pins on the top provide 120V AC power for various elements controlled by the board.
When R is connected (by the thermostat) to Y, W, or G, 120V appears on either COOL, HEAT, or FAN respectively. I have tested this with a voltmeter.
The motor in the air handler has 4 wires connected to it (black, red, yellow, and white).
According to the figure on page 30 of the handler manual (I pasted it below), white is common, black should be connected to COOL, and red should be connected to HEAT. That is how it's been connect since I moved in. Yellow was disconnected (connected to a PARK).
After searching the internet, I found suggestions to connect the yellow wire to FAN to enable the fan-only mode. Here are some references: [1, 2].
Finally, here is my question. The figure also indicates that the black, red, and yellow wires from the motor correspond to different speeds (and they do, I can hear the difference). Why would the highest speed be always used for cooling, medium for fan-only, and the slowest for heating?
What if I didn't have access to 3 different windings on the motor? Is it common to have another board that would provide commutation between what windings one wants to use for what purpose? What can I do if I want it to blow as hard as it does for cooling, but with only the fan on?
Also, is connecting the yellow motor wire to FAN ok, or is there some potential pitfall I should be aware of?



Why would the highest speed be always used for cooling, medium for fan-only, and the slowest for heating?

People usually like it windy when they are trying to cool down and still when they are trying to warm up.
If you want a different speed for fan-only you can connect two of the outputs to the same motor wire.

Also, is connecting the yellow motor wire to FAN ok, or is there some potential pitfall I should be aware of?

If Y or W is active (connected to R) and G is also connected to R what happens on the output terminals?  if only one is live at any time there are no pitfalls, two of then go active at the same time you could damage the motor (test this with nothing,or a lamp, connected to the fan terminal, because otherwise the motor could back-feed the fan terminal giving a false reading).   The diagram shows a relay that prevents both HEAT and COOL going active at the same time, but no mention (at all) is made of FAN in the diagram.
A wire with one of theses "piggy back" quick-disconnects on one end and a regular on the other could  be used to bridge FAN to COOL and allow you to also connect the motor wire,

Image credit google adverts (MOLEX 19011-0037 element-14.com)

The FAN pin gets power only if only G (and neither W nor Y) is active. Otherwise FAN if off. Do you think it's ok to connect FAN and COOL together (to the same motor wire)?

That's good, yes it's absolutely ok.  Ideally use a wire with a piggyback Faston on one end and regular on the other.

Short version: blower-only is a basic documented function.  If it's not working you need to follow logical diagnostic steps, not to modify your system with undocumented hacks.  Verify the thermostat, its wiring, and the control board are doing what they should, and that's it.  The most likely problem is the thermostat's G wire is broken.  Stop reading and go check that.
No, really.  Anyway ... The long version.
"Blowing hard" as you put it, without cooling is pointless.  The system fan is not a fan like one that blows on you to cool you.   It is a circulator that moves all your house air through the handler.  The high speed is to provide the required air flow through the chiller to match its cooling and dehumidifying capacity.  The lower speed is all that is required for the heater.
Fan-only mode extends the time that different parts of the house remain balanced between cycles of heating and cooling.  It mixes up the air. For example if you have a sunny room it keeps that room closer to the temperature of other rooms (notably the one with the thermostat) for longer between cooling cycles.  This function does not usually require high speed.
Your control board energizes the black low speed wire when only the G signal is given.  You can't change that, it's how the board functions.
If for some reason you want full time high speed fan, you can park the black wire and connect the red one to both speed terminals.  I can't see what this would achieve, but it will make heated air cooler so if you are near enough a vent to feel the flow, it may feel cool even though it's heating.
With all that said, according to the instructions and sequence diagrams in the manual, if your thermostat has a fan mode function with an ON setting, you set it, and there is no call for cool or heat, the fan should run at low speed.  Test this at the board: connect R to G directly and you should find 120V on black and 0V on yellow and red.  If that test fails you have a faulty board.  If it succeeds you have a faulty thermostat or it is not wired correctly.
Don't short motor signals together.  That's not a documented capability of the motor, and they don't provide park lugs and instruct you to use them for nothing.
Ignore your medium speed. It has a purpose described in section V.B.3 of the manual, to reduce overheating caused by poor installation.   Leave the yellow wire parked.

Fan-only also pulls air through your handler's air filter. Probably not the most efficient way to "clean" your air, but...

@Matthew during mild weather with neither heating nor cooling, and especially when windows are open, that is a very good point.  If you have a good filter or other treatments, or allergies or other need for it, running the fan can help a lot.   During heating and cooling however, the air is completely circulated dozens of times per day, so extra fan-only cycles probably don't add much "cleaning" but they do help to keep  rooms in balance.

This answer feels like it is ignoring a lot of information in the question? OP has done the debugging steps.... The thermostat is capable of sending a signal on the G wire. When it does, 120V appears on the FAN terminal on the board. Which is apparently not connected to anything. It seems like an installation, and maybe documentation issue; "fan input turns on the fan output" doesn't seem believable as a "failure" to me (but you never know)

@mbrig maybe?  I think I answered everything after "finally here is my question" clearly.  The actual Question (headline) has an inconsistency  that does not need to be resolved in order for this answer to guide OP or anyone to treating this equipment correctly.

@jay613 if you're just trying to answer that part then I would remove the other information which is inconsistent with what OP describes... as it is kind of confusing/misleading as-is. I think the core disconnect is you have written a lot of stuff in the context of the original control board of the furnace but OP says they have a 21D83M-843 board, which is a replacement, which has slightly different terminals to be wired (and apparently functions slightly differently).

@mbrig what I've done is try to provide OP with the means to do the right thing by following the instructions and good practice.  I don't think anything in my answer is wrong.  You are right, it's ambiguous.  But what is ambiguous is both OP's question and the documentation for the replacement board.  (not the linked powerpoint, the actual manual).  It says in one place the FAN terminal is only for replacement in air handlers with an ultra-low-speed continuous fan capability.  OP's does not have that.   It  hints, but does not say, that isn't not used otherwise.   It says that ...[1/2]

[2/2] continuous fan runs at "heat speed" but it does not say which terminals are energized!   The question says the fan works for heat, does not work for "Fan On" and the board does what's expected with R, W, G ... but it does not explicitly say whether HEAT is energized with Fan-On and no call for heat.   I've tried in my answer to provide an approach that allows OP to do the right thing, once all these ambiguities are resolved.  I can't do an interactive diagnosis with him.  And I maintain that ignoring the design by running at high speed all the time solves no problem and may do some harm.

Jasen's answer covers the bulk of your question, I just want to clarify what I think is the cause of some of your confusion; and also perhaps why your system ended up installed like this in the first place.
The wiring and sequence diagram you have in your post is from the original control board on the furnace. The 21D83M-843 control board you say the furnace has, is a replacement. Here is the wiring diagram for it, taken from page 37 of the document you link:

Notice the difference(s) in the connection to the blower? This diagram includes the FAN terminal, which your posted diagram doesn't.
So the answer to "why is it setup like this" seems quite likely to be, that the replacement control board you have does not function exactly like the original board does (the original energizes the HEAT terminal in fan-only mode), and whoever installed it was unaware or ignored the difference.
Some further suggestive (but not quite conclusive) information:
The 21D83M-843 is capable of replacing the 24L8501 board (among others), and when used for that purpose, the FAN terminal takes the place of the ACB LOW terminal (table 2, page 5). What does the ACB LOW terminal do? It's what is energized when the thermostat calls for FAN (see page 27 of the linked manual).
Now, perhaps, there is some switch somewhere to change your board's behavior between the two, or perhaps the heat/cool-to-fan delay option switches also control it. But if so, it is not mentioned anywhere in the manual.

@jay613 your claim does not match the observed reality. When the thermostat calls for fan (G), OP's control board turns the FAN terminal on, not the HEAT terminal. And further, how would the generic replacement board know to change behavior? The option switches, according to the manual, only control the heat/cool to fan off delay.

Yes. The 21D83M-843 control board is a replacement. I did not replace it myself, but I had found another board in the box of the installed one. I can report on the model of the old one later. It's in the attic right now. Your assessment must be correct. Thank you.
